# How can i switch two strings in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Below is my code. Here, i have to switch two of the names in the 2D array but i'm not sure how to do this.

Anyone knows how to do?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Homeworktest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String[][] people = new String[3][3];
            people[0][0] = "April";
            people[0][1] = "Jenny";
            people[0][2] = "Charlie";
            people[1][0] = "Maya";
            people[1][1] = "Daniel";
            people[1][2] = "Felix";
            people[2][0] = "Jack";
            people[2][1] = "Charlotte";
            people[2][2] = "Nick";

            for(int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
                String[] subarrays = seatingChart[i];
                for(int y = 0; y < people.length; y++) {
                    System.out.print(subarrays[y] + " ");
                }

                System.out.println();
            }

            public static void switchSeats(int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Keep the value of the first one in a temporary variable, then replace the first one with the second one, and the second one with the value of the temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

To swap values of two array locations, first, hold one value in a temporary variable, assign the second location's value to the first location and lastly assign the temporary variable's value to the second location.

```
public static void switchSeats(String[][] people, int row1, 
                                       int col1, int row2, int col2) {

   String tmp = people[row1][col1];
   people[row1][col1] = people[row2][col2];
   people[row2][col2] = tmp;

}
```

In the above code, `tmp` serves as the temporary variable.

Comment: This is wrong. Your second statement should be `people[row1][col1] = people[row2][col2];`.